# Puppeteer Protocol error (Page.navigate):

Tags: node.js, linux, puppeteer, redhat

```sh
Error: Protocol error (Page.navigate): Cannot navigate to invalid URL
 at Promise (/home/microservice/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:183:56)
 at new Promise ()
 at CDPSession.send (/home/microservice/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Connection.js:182:12)
 at navigate (/home/microservice/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/FrameManager.js:119:39)
 at FrameManager.navigateFrame (/home/microservice/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/FrameManager.js:96:7)
 at Frame.goto (/home/microservice/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/FrameManager.js:407:37)
 at Frame. (/home/microservice/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:111:23)
 at Page.goto (/home/microservice/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:629:49)
 at Page. (/home/microservice/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:111:23)
 at module.exports (/home/microservice/node_modules/htmltopdf-puppeteer/index.js:19:16)\n at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use http to access the url over network or use file:/// to access the local file

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true, args: ['--no-sandbox']  })
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto("http://google.com");
or 
await page.goto("file:///C:/ec2-user/report.html");
```